# Number of ways to share a variable defined in one PHP file among all the files of a website / application?

Tags: php, global-variables, scope

Now I know if `File1.php` was the file that contained the variable I wanted to share. I can:

1. Include the file where the variable needs to be used from within the file where the variable is declared.

   #### File1.php

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();
       $username="user1";
       $_SESSION['username']=$username;
       include('File2.php');
   ?>
   ```

   And in File2.php, access a username like this:

   ```
   <?php
       echo $username;
   ?>
   ```
2. Include the file with the variable definition into another php file where it's needed.

   #### File3.php

   ```
   <?php
       include('File1.php');
       echo $username;
   ?>
   ```
3. And using Session access the variable in any number of files I want, such as `File5.php`, `File6.php`, etc...

   #### File5.php

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();
       echo $_SESSION['username'];
   ?>
   ```

   #### File6.php

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();
       echo $_SESSION['username'];
   ?>
   ```

Of all these methods, the method using the session is truly the only method you can use to share the variable among multiple files.

What are the other ways to share a variable declared in one file among multiple files?

Comment: Please uncomplicated your questions next time.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie - It's pretty simple if you bother to read it... Please stop wasting your time :)

Comment: Hi All, I'm basically trying to understand php's ability to share a variable application wide i.e. being available to all files directly... just like making a variable call/declaration ... anything that comes closest to this is using session variables... I consider using includes an indirect method and we need to include the file everywhere we need the variable  which might also be  an additional load/ performance bottleneck on the application...

Comment: What's with php's superglobals concept ...intutively the concept suggests variables that should/must be available anywhere and that means in any file or script within the same website/applicatio n... Please see this question as well if it helps ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018156/is-post-in-php-truly-superglobal

Answer (score 3):

1. Include
2. Session
3. Cookie
4. Database
5. Files
6. Constants
7. And what not (custom)

Comment: Please see my updated comments beside the origional question... Thanks for answering though and +1 for listing all the ways...

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is stateless, meaning that each request is completely independent from every other request. Put another way, there is literally no way to pass variables from one page load to another.

However, [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) are a way around this. However, it's important to note that the state is held on the browser side (what cookies to send) and on the server side (what session data may be associated with those cookies), but the connection in between them has no knowledge of this state transfer.

Basically: no, there is no other way than what you have outlined.

Comment: +1 yes that's the only (session/cookie) way i know of ... but i'm just confused with php's superglobal concept... if you'd like please have a look at my updated comments beside the origional question...

Comment: "superglobal" means the variable is available in all scopes *of the current script*. So you can access `$_GET` in a function with no problems, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP5's [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to do this. Create a class called "Constants" or something and override the `__get()` method [(see this)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) to read the values from a file or something.

Using this method you'll be able to write code like this in any file without including stuff.

```
$constants = new Constants();
$myVar = $constants->var_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), like in this example:

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
```

Comment: This doesn't make it accessible in other scripts, unless you use one of the techniques he listed. It's orthogonal to what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP classes, that way you have more options to work with variables with other classes!

Comment: As far as i understand i still need to include the class file inside the file i intend to use the variable... If i missed anything you are trying to explain, explain with an Example please...

Comment: this is Q&A web site, not a tutorial site, I think that you want to use a variable more then once, so if you want to use it more then once dont make a lot of pages and use that variable in all of them, just organize your project with classes. I believe you can write what you want in one file with classes then use those classes

Answer (score -1):

You can also declare it as global:

```
global $variable;
```

Comment: That doesn't make it visible in other scripts, only in the function with that declaration.