# is $_POST in php truly superglobal?

Tags: php, scope, superglobals

Why am i asking this ?  I'm trying hard to fathom php's superglobal concept ... array data/variables for $_POST are only available to the file to which the form  posts back.

They are not available to any of the other files in the Website or Application.

Then why /how is $_POST a superglobal which  by it's intutive meaning should mean any variable that is available anywhere / everywhere including all files in a website/ Application where it was not defined.

Can someone please explain me the logic behind this ?

I'm particularly looking to find a direct approach (i.e simply calling/declaring the variable and not indirect approaches like inclding the file containing the variable etc.)to share variables throughout all files in the Website/ Application.

Comment: You seem to be operating under a possible misconception.  PHP scripts do not persist.  They live for one request, then their working environment is destroyed.  You can't "share data" between multiple scripts in the way that I think you're trying to accomplish.  That and I don't see how the core question you have here is any different than your previous question, which covered using sessions to persist data between requests.

Comment: "Variable" and its "Value" are two different things!

Comment: @DrDan yes i tried testing it, it doesn't throw an error but the value itself is not available however... which defeats the purpose of being a  truly global variable... Thanks for takin out the time to explain this... it did help me in better understanding the concept ...

Comment: What data are you *trying* to share?  Configuration, maybe?

Comment: `$_POST` is defined but contains empty array if nothing is posted back, unless it's disabled from config.

Comment: @Charles something similar to the Global.asax file in Asp.net ... the variables declared inside that file are available to all scripts/files within the Application...

Comment: @user481913, so you're just looking for a global include file with configuration stuff?  Cool.  PHP does that.  Call it whatever you want and put whatever you want in it.  This is usually called the "init" or "bootstrap" file.  Include it in every script that will receive user requests, and you've accomplished your goal.

Comment: @Charles He specifically said he wasn't looking for the approach requiring him to include a file with all the variables, I guess he wants it to be automatic.

Comment: @Barmar, outside of that horrid little misfeature in PHP that permits such a thing, my answer to that is "deal with it."  Or use a Front Controller to manage the insanity.  One or the other.

Comment: @Barmar- yes thanks you understand what i mean... I was just trying to find out if there was something that does this automatically... and you're right my intutive definition for superglobals does not match with php's definition...

Answer (score 2):

Your intuitive definition of superglobal doesn't match how PHP uses the term. The definition of "superglobal" in PHP is that the variable is available in all scopes within the script.  The only difference between ordinary global variables and superglobals is that you don't have to use the `global` keyword to access them within a function or method.

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: yes i agree, although the Session/Cookie variables is the nearest possible thing that matches the concept as they are available to any file in the Application... I was just looking for more ways other than session and cookies...

Comment: PHP scripts aren't persistent, they run once and then end. Session data and cookies are persistent. Session data is stored on disk and cookie data is sent every request. If you need GET or POST data available in the script you are running, then you have to send the data in the HTTP request.